# Using methods defined in a interface to call the clone method

Tags: java, interface, copy, clone

So to keep it short and simple i have a list of shapes List these are all shapes (Circle, square ect) that implement my Shape interface.

Now im trying to deep clone/copy every shape on this list and place it in. a new list. 
I have made all the shapes implement Clonable and made my own methods for making deeps copies of them.

The problem is i cant reach the clone method when they are simply defined as Shapes. 
My question is how do i get a hold of the clone method without having to cast them into concrete shapes.

I have been thinking about it and googling it but i cant seem to find a proper answer. 
And so i got an idea.

could i add a method "void callCloneMethod();" in my shapes interface 
and have the implementation call the clone() method of each concrete shape? 
IOW can a interface implemented method call non interface implemented methods. ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just Realised that the interface would have be generic in order to return the right type of cloned object and then i cant use the List<Shape> list cause i will be using a raw type... i already had this problem.... So i guess my question is how can i clone these shapes without casting them to shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to let your Shape interface extend the Cloneable interface? This should allow you to call the method for any Shape, if i am not mistaken. You should then of course implement the clone method.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is the Clonable interface does not act contain the method. its just used to avoid having to throw CloneNotSupportedException. The clone method belongs to Object and is called with super.clone();

Comment: Sry, i am not sure i get your question right, but why not just add your own clone method to your Shape interface, wich then lets you implement it for your shapes. Make it return shape and implement it in a way, in which it makes a new object with same e.g. size.

Comment: Just wanted to use Javas ready made method i guess. But thx for the help i guess you are right i could just do that.